# why the atoi function is not working?

Tags: c, atoi

The program stops working.
Even if I put only one int.
I tried many different ways but can't figure out what is wrong.
I am trying to take input of integers separated by space.
There can be any no of integers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,j=0;
    int b[100];
    char a[100];
    fgets(a,100,stdin);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
        b[i] = atoi(a[j]);
        j=j+2;
    }
    for(i=0;i<strlen(b);i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",b[j]);
    }` and `b[i] = atoi(&a[j]);` and `j<strlen(a)`

Comment: This shouldn't even compile without `<string.h>`, as you are using `strlen()`.

Comment: It does not work even if I do not use strlen

Comment: remember atoi needs a character array not a single character

Comment: What is the aim of this program? You forgot to mention that in the question.

Comment: [fix like this](http://ideone.com/9HAOEx)

Comment: Just change *b[i] = atoi(a[j]);* to *b[i] = a[j];*

Comment: @ApoorvAgarwal, What is this program supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the prototype of atoi you have to use a character array but you are sending a character only.`atoi(str[i])`

```
int atoi(const char *str)


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int val;
   char str[20];

   strcpy(str, "98993489");
   val = atoi(str);
   printf("String value = %s, Int value = %d\n", str, val);


   return(0);
}
```

Comment: [C library function - atoi()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)

Comment: so what can i do?

Comment: remove those loops and follow the above mentioned syntax

Comment: How do i input some unknown number of integers separated by space?

Comment: You can use a 2-D Array to store them. char data[5][20] and follow the syntax
`b[i]=atoi(data[i]));`

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i += 2)
{
    b[j] = a[i];
    j++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

though atoi() accepts only a string argument or u can say constant char pointer and str[i] is nothing but a pointer pointing at a single character of the character array.
Therefore once we pass atoi(str[i]) , that means we are passing a character to the function, which will give an error.
Therefore you must pass the address of that particular character from where you want to convert the substring into a number i.e. atoi(&str[i]).